# does bash `shift` command change argument count `$#`

Tags: bash, arguments

When I use the bash `shift` command, does that change the argument count in `$#`?

> **Note from author:** When I had this question I did not find it (yet) on this community. Therefore I simply tried it and got my answer.
>   Because I thought it might help others I posted what I learned here as
>   ***a self-answered question***.

Answer (score 13):

Yes is does, [it's explicitly required in the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#shift):

> `shift [n]` The positional parameters shall be shifted. Positional parameter 1 shall be assigned the value of parameter (1+n), *[...]* and the parameter '#' is updated to reflect the new number of positional parameters.

Consider this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "$#"
shift
echo "$#"
```

Calling it like `script-file first second third` will print `3` followed by `2`.

This means we can do things like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while [[ "$#" > 0 ]] ; do
    echo "$1"
    shift
done
```

...which would print the arguments one by one on their own line.

Comment: ... or read the standard that says [_"...the parameter '#' is updated to reflect the new number of positional parameters._"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#shift)

Comment: That last code snippet could be replaced by `printf '%s\n' "$@"` or `for arg do echo "$arg"; done`. However, this would obviously not make use of `shift`, only produce identical output.